# Find all the solutions of the initial value problem for a first order non-linear equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the initial value problem: $$ y'= \frac{10}{3}xy^{2/5}, \qquad y(0)=0 \qquad \qquad (1) $$
where $ x\in \mathbb{R} $.

The first order equation is not linear in the form: 
$$ y'=f(x,y)$$ and some considerations can be done on the existence of possible solutions.

First we note that $f(x,y) \text{ is continuous} \quad \forall (x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 $ and that  $ \frac{d}{dy}f(x,y)=\frac{4}{3}xy^{-3/5} $ is continuous $\forall \, (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 $ s.t.  $ y \neq 0 $.

Thus $(1) $ will not have an unique solution in general.

1. One solution is trivial and it is: $y(x) = 0 \quad \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$;
2. Another solution different from the trivial one can be obtained separating the variables: $$ y^{-2/5} y'=\frac{10}{3}x $$
   $$ \int y^{-2/5} \, \mathrm{d}y = \frac{5}{3}x^2 + c $$
   $$ y(x) = \left (x^2 +\frac{3}{5}c \right)^{5/3} $$ 
   from which using $y(0)=0$ we get $c=0$ and hence the second solution 
   $$ y(x) = x^{10/3} $$

My book says that there are other 2 solutions to the initial value problem $(1)$ but I cannot see them.

How could I find the missing solutions?

Comment: Is the x-axis a solution to this problem?

Comment: @imranfat $y=0$ is indeed a solution but I have already considered it in point 1.

Comment: Does the book provide the answers? I would like to know...

Comment: @imranfat no, unfortunately it doesn't :/

Comment: Do you think the y-axis would work? After all, substituting x=0 in the DFQ also gives y'=0 and y(0)=0 is also on the y-axis...Just a thought

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other solutions are $$y(x) = \cases{ (x^2 - a^2)^{5/3} & if $x \le a$\cr
                                         0 & if $a < x \le b$\cr
                                    (x^2 - b^2)^{5/3} & if $x > b$\cr}$$
where $-\infty \le a < 0 < b \le \infty$.

Comment: That's even better,thanks! But I guess in the first case you meant "if x<a"

Comment: $x=a$ could go in either of the two first cases, but should be listed in only one.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer, I write it down here since it could interest also someone else.

A funtion $ y(x) $ to be a solution of $(1)$ must satisfy two conditions:

$ y(x) $ must be differentiable on $ \mathbb{R}$ and satisfy $(1)$. We can see then that both:

$$ y(x) = \begin{cases} x^{10/3} & \text{if } x \geq 0 \\
0 & \text{if } x < 0 \end{cases}$$ 
and

$$ y(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if } x \geq 0 \\ 
x^{10/3} & \text{if } x < 0  \end{cases}$$ 
are differentiable in $ \mathbb{R}$ and are solutions of $(1)$ .